# Как вставить картинку до и после видео при помощи ffmpeg (avconv)? [Решение]

Tags: видео, ffmpeg

Для начала нужно узнать параметры видеофайла:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi
```

У меня это:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'file.avi':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
      Duration: 00:10:38.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 814 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 672 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

.avi из .MTS получаю так:

```
for invideo in *.MTS; do ffmpeg -i "$invideo" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 "Converted/${invideo%%.MTS}.avi"; done;
```

Далее, нужно сделать видео из картинок с теми-же параметрами.

В графическом редакторе создаём картинки Начало.png и Окончание.png с разрешением 1280x720.

Создаём видео из картинок:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Начало2.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 501 -vf "fade=out:899:1:alpha=1"  -sar 1:1 -aspect 16:9   -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало2.avi
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Окончание2.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 501 -vf "fade=out:899:1:alpha=1" -sar 1:1 -aspect 16:9 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Окончание2.avi
```

Накладываем звуковую дорожку:

```
ffmpeg -i 00019.wav -i Начало2.avi -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало_звук.avi
ffmpeg -i 00019.wav -i Окончание2.avi -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Окончание_звук.avi
```

Для простоты, звуковую дорожку я взял из видео файла, записанного той-же видеокамерой в тишине:

```
ffmpeg -i 00019.MTS -c:a pcm_s16le -vn 00019.wav
```

Обрезаем до нужной длительности:

```
ffmpeg -i Начало_звук.avi -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало_10с.avi
ffmpeg -i Окончание_звук.avi -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Окончание_10с.avi
```

Приклеиваем ко всем файлам текущего каталога:

```
for invideo in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i concat:"info/Начало_10с.avi|$invideo|info/Окончание_10с.avi" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 "${invideo%%.avi}_mod.avi"; done;
```

Ошибки при склеивании у меня были из-за разных SAR , DAR и аудиокодека склеиваемых видео файлов.

Благодарю уважаемого [Sergiks](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7161/sergiks) за подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

У объединяемых через [concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) клипов должны быть идентичные размеры, кодеки, формат пикселя. Там, где создаёте видео из картинки после `-i Начало.png` попробуйте добавить `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Для промежуточных видео, которые потом объединяете, вместо `h264` лучше использовать кодек без потерь, напр. `ffvhuff`. Т.е. исходное видео переводите в этот кодек, картинковидео создавайте в этом кодеке, объединяйте в этот кодек. И в конце отдельно уже жмите в h264 – быстрее и качественнее будет. Но понадобится больше места на диске на время работы.

Создать видео нужной длины из картинки можно за одну операцию.

Comment: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Начало.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 501 -vf "fade=out:899:1:alpha=1" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало.avi` скорость без изменений относительно libx264 , а то и медленнее.     С `-pix_fmt yuv420p` те же ошибки. Не могу сюда выложить полный текст того что делаю, говорит превышена длинна сообщения.

Comment: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i Начало.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -vframes 501 -vf "fade=out:899:1:alpha=1" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало.avi

ffmpeg -i 00018.wav -i Начало.avi -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 Начало_звук.avi

ffmpeg -i Начало_звук.avi -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 Начало_10с.avi

for invideo in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i concat:"info/Начало_10с.avi|$invideo|info/Окончание_10с.avi" -s hd720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 "${invideo%%.avi}_mod.avi"; done; ` вот . Окончание_10c.avi так-же делаю. Перенос строки не отображает...

Comment: А что выведет `ffmpeg -i Начало_звук.avi` и `ffmpeg -i любойИз.avi`?

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Разобрался. Были разные SAR , DAR и аудиокодеки склеиваемых файлов.